# Performance of fopen vs stat

Tags: c, file-io, fopen

I'm writing several C programs for an embedded system where every bit of performance we can squeeze out will matter.  Part of that is accessing log files.  When determining if a file exists, is there any performance difference between using open / fopen, and stat ? I've been using stat on the assumption that it only has to do a quick check against the file system, whereas fopen would have to actually gain access to a file and manipulate internal data structures before returning.  Is there any merit to this ?

Comment: It would be very easy to write  a small program to test this, which is what you should do for all performance related issues.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`stat` is probably better, since it doesn't have to allocate resources for actually reading the file.  You won't have to call `fclose` to release those resources, and you may also benefit from caching of recently checked files.

When it doubt, test it out.  Time a big loop that checks for 1000 files using each method, with the appropriate mix of filenames that exist and don't exist.

If you have the source code for `stat` and `fopen`, you should be able to read through it and get an idea as to which will require more resources.

Comment: stat actually had 3X better performance for checking file existence than fopen on our embedded boxes, I was kind of surprised.  Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 4):

stat() does not not to create any user-side memory data structures. No matter how aggressive your caching policy, stat will not try pre-read the file's data. I think stat() is a safer bet.

How about access()?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to squeeze out performance with respect to querying file existence and opening files, minimize the number of `fopen` and `stat` calls in general. The call to the file system should be way more expensive than anything the runtime does to translate it.

Answer (score 0):

For only testing file existence, stat() would be preferred over fopen().

However, depending upon your setup, it could be worthwhile to use lstat() instead of stat().

Comment: Is there a perf difference between stat and lstat when the file is never a symbolic link?

Comment: @JosephGarvin - There should not be any appreciable difference in performance when the file is never a symbolic link.